# Android TextView top image not rendering properly on 2.3

Tags: android, image, android-layout, textview, rendering

When I run my android application in Android version >=4 I got this out put(I didn't tested in android version 3):
[image]

When run the same application in android version 2.3 I got a bit different output:
[image]

You can see in second screenshot the image for about button is not visible. But when I try run the same application several times on 2.3 some times I got about image visible.
Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include layout="@layout/actionbar_with_right_button" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/settings_text_view_drawable_padding"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/snooze_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="showRemainderSnoozeSettings"
            android:padding="@dimen/settings_text_view_padding"
            android:text="@string/snooze" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/settings_text_view_drawable_padding"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/help_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="showFaq"
            android:padding="@dimen/settings_text_view_padding"
            android:text="@string/help" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/settings_text_view_drawable_padding"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/about_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="showAbout"
            android:padding="@dimen/settings_text_view_padding"
            android:text="@string/about" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I didn't understand why this is happening.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue.
**Edit :** 
One more important thing I forgot to mention when I changed android:drawableTop="@drawable/about_button" to android:drawableTop="@drawable/help_button" of about `TextView`. It worked perfectly. So it can be an issue of my about_button image. So I recreated the about image again and put in all drawable folder. Even after that also I didn't get any +ve result. This issue only in 2.3 or less.
Thanks

Comment: I think problem is with the drawable padding you have set.Try with  removing that or reduce the padding.Instead of padding you can set top_margin to the Textview.

Comment: @Nishant I need to have some gap between text and top drawable in that `TextView
`.

Comment: Then try with giving padding_top to any one either to TextView or to its top drwable and reduce the padding amount also.

Comment: Padding amount less only

Comment: I didn't understand giving padding_top to TextView or drawable. See here drawable is not a separate ImageView. Its a also a part of TextView

Comment: There is no need of setting `android:layout_gravity="center"` to scroll view add `layout_margin_top` attribute to scroll view to 10 dp and replace `android:gravity="center"` in linearLayout to `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`.Hope this will help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35257/discussion-between-vishal-vijay-and-nishant)

Comment: You can first clear this thing: don't use `android:drawableTop` (you might not have a drawable there). How do you set the drawables anyway - where do you insert the round green pictures? Use `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` to set the relations between the Views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this help you:

**Seems like this is a bug with android**, where sometimes the first image in the `drawable folder` doesn't get displayed.....

I had a similar bug - a particular drawable was not being displayed, no matter in what ImageView. So I Added a dummy image called `aaaa.png` to the `drawable folder` and problem was solved....

Comment: Let me try this and let you know